# Transfer data from one memcached server to another

Tags: php, memcached

Currently we are storing our user sessions in memcached, our web apps are running with PHP 5.3.6 and Apache 2.2.3.

We will be replacing our memcached server, I am wondering if there is a way we can transfer the data from one memcached server to another so that the user sessions are still there. (To minimize downtime)

Although I have read from the FAQ http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#How_can_you_dump_data_from_or_load_data_into_memcached? that it is probably not possible to do that...but I am hoping if someone have some tools or workaround to achieve this.

Thanks!

Best regards

Comment: :( not sure if I posted this on the wrong section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably add some code into your system that, when a user visits, writes the session into both the new server and the old one, and then let them run in parallel for a while, then turn off the old server. That way you can "warm up" the new server without actually depending on it, and then swap over once most of the sessions are moved over.

You'll still lose some sessions, but the most frequent visitors won't notice anything because their sessions will have been moved over.

Comment: Thanks Amber, is a great suggestion. But I doubt we are able to tune our codes at this point to achieve this.

Comment: Then you're probably just going to have to swap it out. Memcache isn't designed to be a persistent store - it's best to design your website so that you can handle losing the contents of memcache (or if not, run a multi-machine memcache cluster so that you can rotate individual servers in and out without losing the entire cluster).

Comment: You might want to check out tcpcopy (http://code.google.com/p/tcpcopy/) it will allow you to split a tcp stream to both of your memcached servers, new and old.

Answer (score 16):

It's possible with memcached-tool.

```
memcached-tool 10.1.2.30:11211 dump | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Comment: in case you need to find it, memcached-tool is found in `/usr/share/memcached/scripts` on debian.

Comment: I wrote some scripts to automate this process on startup using systemd. https://github.com/ticpu/tools/tree/master/memcached-replicate

Comment: This worked, I successfully moved my memcache data to a new server without any issue.

Comment: On big memcached (~500k items), I had to dump into a temporary file and inject it on other node.